# Execute code between migrations

Tags: sql, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I want to "move" field (Nickname) from one entity (Driver) to another (AspNetUsers). So, first migration is creating field Nickname for AspNetUsers, second migration remove it from Driver. But I also want to copy data (where it's possible) from Driver to AspNetUsers. Of course, I can do it by cursor in T-SQL, start the first migration, then SQL script, then the second manually, but in this case I can't pull it to GIT without detail description how to execute. I want to include this SQL script between migrations. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your custom code inside the Up() and Down() methods of the migration to copy the data forward and backwards(!).

See here towards the bottom:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx